# How do I count the occurences of characters of a partition in python?

Tags: python, list, counter, partition

I have a large file containing sequences; I want to analyze only the last set of characters, which happen to be of variable length. In each line I would like to take the first character and last character of each set in a text file and count the total instances of those characters.

Here is an example of the data in the file:

-1iqd_BA_0_CDRH3.pdb kabat H3 **P**DPDAFD**V**

-1iqw_HL_0_CDRH3.pdb kabat H3 **N**RDYSNNWYFD**V**

I want to take the first character after the "H3" and the last character (both in bold in example). 
The output for these two lines should be:

first Counter({'N': 1, 'P': 1})

last Counter({'V': 2})

This is what I have done so far:

```
f = open("C:/CDRH3.txt", "r")
from collections import Counter
grab = 1
for line in f:
   line=line.rstrip()
   left,sep,right=line.partition(" H3 ")
   if sep:
         AminoAcidsFirst = right[:grab] 
         AminoAcidsLast = right[-grab:]
print ("first ",Counter(line[:] for line in AminoAcidsFirst))
print ("last ",Counter(line[:] for line in AminoAcidsLast))
f.close()
```

This prints the counts of only the last line of data which looks like:

```
first Counter({'N': 1})
last Counter({'V': 1})
```

How do I count all these characters in all lines in the file?
Notes: 
Printing (AminoAcidsFirst) or (AminoAcidsLast) gives the desired list of all the lines in vertical but I can't count it or output it to a file. Writing to a new file will only write the characters of the last line of the original file.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to keep the counts for the first and last characters separate or could they be in the same Counter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create 2 empty lists and append in each loop like so:

```
f = open("C:/CDRH3.txt", "r")
from collections import Counter
grab = 1
AminoAcidsFirst = []
AminoAcidsLast = []
for line in f:
   line=line.rstrip()
   left,sep,right=line.partition(" H3 ")
   if sep:
         AminoAcidsFirst.append(right[:grab])
         AminoAcidsLast.append(right[-grab:])
print ("first ",Counter(line[:] for line in AminoAcidsFirst))
print ("last ",Counter(line[:] for line in AminoAcidsLast))
f.close()
```

Here:

1. Creation of empty list:

   `AminoAcidsFirst = []
   AminoAcidsLast = []`
2. Appending in each loop:

   `AminoAcidsFirst.append(right[:grab])
   AminoAcidsLast.append(right[-grab:])`

Comment: This worked really well for me using Py3 and I was able to output to a file. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

No need for Counter: simply grab the last token after `split`ing and count the first and last characters:

```
first_counter = {}
last_counter = {}
for line in f:
   line=line.split()[-1]   # grab the last token
   first_counter[line[0]] = first_counter.get(line[0], 0) + 1
   last_counter[line[-1]] = last_counter.get(line[-1], 0) + 1    

print("first ", first_counter)
print("last ", last_counter)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
first  {'P': 1, 'N': 1}
last  {'V': 2}
```

Comment: This returned an error: `Line 4, in 0. builtins.IndexError: list index out of range`. Using Py3. Changed print () format. I'm not sure if there is something else missing. Thanks though.

Comment: @BioEng-Mike yes, `print` has moved from builtin to a function in Python3 (so you need to add the brackets). I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Two important things I would like to point out

1. never reveal path of file on your computer, this is especially applicable if you are from scientific community
2. your code can be more pythonic using `with...as` approach

And now the program

```
from collections import Counter

filePath = "C:/CDRH3.txt"
AminoAcidsFirst, AminoAcidsLast = [], [] # important! these should be lists

with open(filePath, 'rt') as f:  # rt not r. Explicit is better than implicit
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()
        left, sep, right = line.partition(" H3 ")
        if sep:
            AminoAcidsFirst.append( right[0] ) # really no need of extra grab=1 variable
            AminoAcidsLast.append( right[-1] ) # better than right[-grab:]
print ("first ",Counter(AminoAcidsFirst))
print ("last ",Counter(AminoAcidsLast))
```

Don't do `line.strip()[-1]` because `sep` verification is important

**OUTPUT**

```
first  {'P': 1, 'N': 1}
last  {'V': 2}
```

**Note:** Data files can get really large, and you might run into memory issues or computer hanging. So, might I suggest lazy read? Folloing is more robust program

```
from collections import Counter

filePath = "C:/CDRH3.txt"
AminoAcidsFirst, AminoAcidsLast = [], [] # important! these should be lists

def chunk_read(fileObj, linesCount = 100):
    lines = fileObj.readlines(linesCount)
    yield lines

with open(filePath, 'rt') as f:  # rt not r. Explicit is better than implicit
    for aChunk in chunk_read(f):
        for line in aChunk:
            line = line.rstrip()
            left, sep, right = line.partition(" H3 ")
            if sep:
                AminoAcidsFirst.append( right[0] ) # really no need of extra grab=1 variable
                AminoAcidsLast.append( right[-1] ) # better than right[-grab:]
print ("first ",Counter(AminoAcidsFirst))
print ("last ",Counter(AminoAcidsLast))
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on not revealing the file location. The first set of code worked just fine for my purposes. The second file worked once I adjusted the 'linesCount' to equal the number of total # of characters in the file. I'm looking at files about 36 kb in size with at most 1000 lines, so the first version is sufficient. Thank you! It is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you put statements at the *bottom* of or after your for loop to print `AminoAcidsFirst` and `AminoAcidsLast`, you will see that on each iteration you are just assigning a new value.  Your intent should be to collect, contain or accumulate these values,  before feeding them to `collections.Counter`.

```
s = ['-1iqd_BA_0_CDRH3.pdb kabat H3 PDPDAFDV', '-1iqw_HL_0_CDRH3.pdb kabat H3 NRDYSNNWYFDV']
```

An immediate fix for your code would be to accumulate the characters:

```
grab = 1
AminoAcidsFirst = ''
AminoAcidsLast = ''
for line in s:
   line=line.rstrip()
   left,sep,right=line.partition(" H3 ")
   if sep:
         AminoAcidsFirst += right[:grab] 
         AminoAcidsLast += right[-grab:]
print ("first ",collections.Counter(AminoAcidsFirst))
print ("last ",collections.Counter(AminoAcidsLast))
```

Another approach would be to produce the characters on demand. Define a generator function that will yield the things you want to count

```
def f(iterable):
    for thing in iterable:
        left, sep, right = thing.partition(' H3 ')
        if sep:
            yield right[0]
            yield right[-1]
```

Then feed that to `collections.Counter`

```
z = collections.Counter(f(s))
```

Or using a file as the data source:

```
with open('myfile.txt') as f1:
    # lines is a generator expression
    # that produces stripped lines
    lines = (line.strip() for line in f1)
    z = collections.Counter(f(lines))
```